# Querying entities A, Hibernate adds UNION with table B

Tags: java, hibernate

(Class B extends class A, A has @Inheritance strategy of "TABLE_PER_CLASS".)

I am querying only A now. B should not be involved at all in the query.

HQL looks OK:

`select generatedAlias0 from A as generatedAlias0 where ( generatedAlias0.id in (1, 2, 3) ) and ( generatedAlias0.dateDeleted is null )`

...somehow Hibernate translates it into this:

```
-- simplified for readability sake
SELECT
  *
FROM (
  SELECT * FROM A
  UNION ALL SELECT * FROM B -- <-- ???
)
WHERE .....
```

Why? STAHP!

(When removing the @Inheritance annotation the UNION is gone yet the B-column references remain, making the final query invalid.)

Comment: *B should not be involved at all in the query*: yes, it should. B extends A, so B **is an** A. Lion extends Animal. You have a zoo full of animals, some of them are lions. You're looking for all animals named Simba. Why would Simba the lion not be in the results?

Comment: I see what you mean and you are correct. But my scenario is more like A being cars, B being *the same cars* just wiht some extra information. (B is a view of A-JOIN-X where X is the extra information.) Now UNION means I get duplicate records when querying A.

Comment: Then your model doesn't match with your database design. table per class means that lions are stored in one table, and tigers in a different table. B shouldn't extend A. Or A and B should both extend a common class annotated with MappedSuperclass, to avoid duplicating the common fields in the two entities.

Comment: That is Very Debatable, but besides the point. Thanks :)